# Sending extra data to templates using class-based views in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have recently started using Django frameworks class-based views.

Assume I have a model Book. Is it possible using class-based views, to besides sending one object of type Book, send a boolean value, which I could set in the view?

For example, I would like the view to send the dictionary context = {object: Book, green: True} to a template.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course it's possible.

You can override `get_context_data` and add anything you like.

**Edit**

`get_object` gets the specific database object that the view is displaying/editing. In the default implementation, `get_context_data` returns a dictionary consisting of the value returned by `get_object`. You can call the superclass method then add your own values to the result.

Comment: And what is the get_object function for?

Comment: So basically I would like to mix this: http://chriskief.com/2012/12/29/django-generic-detailview-without-a-pk-or-slug/ with updating the context dictionary. How do get_context_data and get_object interact?